# Tableau Prep - System error: AqlProcessor evaluation failed: No more data to read from socket

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-prep

My Tableau prep was updated to 2021.4 this morning. After the update, a flow of mine started encountering an error when refresh. The error message is "System error: AqlProcessor evaluation failed: No more data to read from socket". I was able to identify the error happened on an Aggregation step, I attached the Aggregate in the screenshot. Basically I added an output step right before and after the Aggregate 7 to test the location of failure, the output before Aggregate 7 worked but the output after Aggregate 7 failed.
[image]
However, when I put mouse on Aggregate 7, it shows the sample result. I'm not sure what does the error mean. It only happened after the tableau prep upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to 2022.2 , they have resolved it

https://www.tableau.com/support/releases/prep/2022.2.1

When running a flow with a Join and Union step, it would sometimes result in the following error, "AqlProcessor evaluation failed: no such column "

1344295